# No way to fix 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, pip

I know this question has been asked many times but I still can't get it to work. I have added the path variables python37 as well as python37\scripts. I have reinstalled python ensuring pip was selected to install. I have verified that pip.exe is inside my scripts folder, but still nothing seems to work.

Comment: `python -m pip install module_name`?

Comment: Better: `py -m pip`. Windows Python recommends not messing with your path in the first place and using the py launcher instead.

Comment: using  py -m pip install I was able to make it work. Thank you very much.

Comment: when you just enter python in the terminal check to which python version it is pointing to or use pip3 to install the pacakge

Answer (score 3):

try using `pip3 (your command)` or `python(3) -m pip (your command)`. If neither of those work, you may have to reinstall python.